# Can do istikhara for marrying (or not marrying) a girl from a particular country?

Tags: nikah, istikharah

I'm a 28yr old Sunni man. I am wondering if I can do istikhara for marrying (or not marrying) a girl from a particular country.

Comment: If you down vote please leave a critical comment to help the OP to improve or elaborate his post or at least learn what is/wrong.

Comment: IMO this question has the aftertaste of racism which is prohibited in Islam, as you seem to prefer people or women from one country, while you seem to dislike or disprefer people or women from an other. As in dua' you are not allowed to ask for something prohibited logically a prayer of Istikhara on that purpose would also be considered as not allowed.

Comment: I wanted to exclude my parents country as a place where to look for a wife since it's there were my family and relatives suggest I should look for a wife in. I thought an istikhara would make it easier for me to abonden that option. Also I have a particular country that I favor to look for a wife in I thought an istikhara would help.to guide me if it's a good option.

Comment: Still this leaves a no good aftertaste, but I'm not an expert, but I'd say first of all you may perform du'a asking Allah a good wife. Then once you may have one in mind then you would/should make istikhara to ask help from Allah to find out whether she is suitable or not. But as is your question seems a bit wrong. See for example http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/24233/istikhara-in-islam?rq=1

Comment: It would be better if you can make the question general and not personal, like "Does Dua' Istikhara hold in this case?" and likewise"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Istikhara &marriage](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/33205/istikhara-marriage)

Answer (score 2):

You can do istikhara on anything, any matter you are going to do. And specially when you are going to marry, it's a big step and you should do istikhara.

I can't think of any reason you might not do istikhara on anything you want to do.